# Using pyVmomi with Django

Tags: django, pyvmomi

i'm trying to use pyVmomi with Django, is there any way (if there is, what is the most recommended way) to pass the serviceInstance between views?

Thanks.

Comment: tried using sessions, but the serviceInstance object is "not pickable". also tried to see if i can just save the session key and then create a new instance and import the key to it (instead of creating a new session) but that didnt work either.

Answer (score 0):

According to Shawn Hartsock (the current VMWare employee maintaing pyVmomi) you cant connect with out a [login](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples/blob/master/samples/suds-to-pyvmomi.py#L113) but between that sample and [this sample](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples/blob/master/samples/pyvmomi-to-suds.py) it should show how to use the same session which you said you were not able to do.